# how to check the jira workflow

Tags: jira, atlassian-sourcetree

can we know the issue is working under the workflow or not in jira ..?
We have tried creating workflows and assigned them to the issues but not able to know if the issue is working according to the workflow assigned or not.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the View Workflow link in an issue